# prevent mysql user change password of other user

Tags: mysql

I have two users:

> **user1** : all privleges, no grant option.
>
> **user2** : all privleges, with grant option.

**user1**, connect to database and change password of **user2**.
How can I prevent this ?

Comment: user1 has no grant option. but can change user2's password.

Comment: Sorry, revoke `UPDATE` privilege for the `mysql` system schema.

Comment: Sorry, Not good idea ... there is more than 20 databases, and i should set privilege to them one by one :(  by the now, user1 has global privilege for all databases. in addition, by revoking update on mysql, user1 won't be able to change his password.

Answer (score 0):

The [`GRANT` privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option) isn't related to passwords. It determines if user is able to change permissions for others.

In [Set Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) we can read:

> Setting the password for a named account (with a FOR clause) requires the **`UPDATE` privilege for the `mysql` system schema**. Setting the password for yourself (for a nonanonymous account with no FOR clause) requires no special privileges.

The recommend way to change passwords is the `ALTER USER` statement but that [documentation section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html) basically states the same:

> In most cases, `ALTER USER` requires the global `CREATE USER` privilege, or the **`UPDATE` privilege for the `mysql` system schema**.